How to make Flutter app for VR headset in immersive view?
I am developing a Flutter app for viewing 360° videos and want to enable full VR immersive playback on a Pico Neo 3 VR headset.
Currently, I am using the vr_player package (version 0.2.2) for 360° video playback. While it works perfectly on mobile devices, the video appears in a separate window when running on the VR headset.
My goal is to display the video in an immersive full-screen mode without any borders, utilizing the capabilities of the VR headset (Pico Neo 3 with Android OS).
Does anyone know how to achieve this? Are there specific packages, platform configurations, or native Android methods that can help integrate Flutter with the VR headset for full immersive video playback?
My code sample:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:vr_player/vr_player.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: VideoPlayerPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class VideoPlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerPage({super.key});

  @override
  _VideoPlayerPageState createState() => _VideoPlayerPageState();
}

class _VideoPlayerPageState extends State<VideoPlayerPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late VrPlayerController _viewPlayerController;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  bool _isShowingBar = false;
  bool _isPlaying = false;
  bool _isFullScreen = false;
  bool _isVideoFinished = false;
  bool _isLandscapeOrientation = false;
  bool _isVolumeSliderShown = false;
  bool _isVolumeEnabled = true;
  late double _playerWidth;
  late double _playerHeight;
  String? _duration;
  int? _intDuration;
  bool isVideoLoading = false;
  bool isVideoReady = false;
  String? _currentPosition;
  double _currentSliderValue = 0.1;
  double _seekPosition = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController);
    _toggleShowingBar();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _toggleShowingBar() {
    switchVolumeSliderDisplay(show: false);

    _isShowingBar = !_isShowingBar;
    if (_isShowingBar) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _playerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _playerHeight =
    _isFullScreen ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : _playerWidth / 2;
    _isLandscapeOrientation =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _toggleShowingBar,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            VrPlayer(
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              onCreated: onViewPlayerCreated,
              width: _playerWidth,
              height: _playerHeight,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void cardBoardPressed() {
    _viewPlayerController.toggleVRMode();
  }

  Future<void> fullScreenPressed() async {
    await _viewPlayerController.fullScreen();
    setState(() {
      _isFullScreen = !_isFullScreen;
    });

    if (_isFullScreen) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      ]);
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [],
      );
    } else {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> playAndPause() async {
    if (_isVideoFinished) {
      await _viewPlayerController.seekTo(0);
    }

    if (_isPlaying) {
      await _viewPlayerController.pause();
    } else {
      await _viewPlayerController.play();
    }

    setState(() {
      _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
      _isVideoFinished = false;
    });
  }

  void onViewPlayerCreated (
      VrPlayerController controller,
      VrPlayerObserver observer,
      ) async {
    _viewPlayerController = controller;

    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

    observer
      ..onStateChange = onReceiveState
      ..onDurationChange = onReceiveDuration
      ..onPositionChange = onChangePosition
      ..onFinishedChange = onReceiveEnded;
    await _viewPlayerController.loadVideo(
      videoPath:
      '/storage/emulated/0/Download/v.mp4',
    );
    await fullScreenPressed();
  }

  void onReceiveState(VrState state) async{
    switch (state) {
      case VrState.loading:
        setState(() {
          isVideoLoading = true;
        });
        break;
      case VrState.ready:
        setState(() {
          isVideoLoading = false;
          isVideoReady = true;
        });
        await _viewPlayerController.play();
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = true;
        });
        break;
      case VrState.buffering:
        _viewPlayerController.toggleVRMode();
      case VrState.idle:
        break;
    }
  }

  void onReceiveDuration(int millis) {
    setState(() {
      _intDuration = millis;
      _duration = millisecondsToDateTime(millis);
    });
  }

  void onChangePosition(int millis) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = millisecondsToDateTime(millis);
      _seekPosition = millis.toDouble();
    });
  }

  // ignore: avoid_positional_boolean_parameters
  void onReceiveEnded(bool isFinished) {
    setState(() {
      _isVideoFinished = isFinished;
    });
  }

  void onChangeVolumeSlider(double value) {
    _viewPlayerController.setVolume(value);
    setState(() {
      _isVolumeEnabled = value != 0;
      _currentSliderValue = value;
    });
  }

  void switchVolumeSliderDisplay({required bool show}) {
    setState(() {
      _isVolumeSliderShown = show;
    });
  }

  String millisecondsToDateTime(int milliseconds) =>
      setDurationText(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));

  String setDurationText(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return '$n';
      return '0$n';
    }

    final twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return '${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds';
  }
}

